Magento2 stripe module lastest version made the cart total to zero composer require "stripe/module-payments:3.5.5" "stripe/stripe-payments:3.5.0"
When i upgrade the Magento2 stripe version to 4.0.9, the cart page and checkout page grand total become zero.
composer require "stripe/module-payments:4.0.9" "stripe/stripe-payments:4.0.0" "stripe/stripe-php:13.15.0"


try it without '--ignore-platform-reqs'. If you really need that maybe the latest version is not compatible with tour settings.

Sanaullah Ahmad
Please check the
var/log/system.log
var/log/exeption.log
file, actual error is available in that file, you need to check that.
